# Arrow Functions en (IE) Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Tengo AngularJS (1.5.5) y haciendo testing, no funcionan las arrow functions en Internet Explorer 11, tengo el siguiente código:

```
return availability.price && availability.options.filter(x => x.leadTime >= 0).length > 0;
```

Y también en este otro bloque genera error:

```
.then(result => { console.log(result); })
.finally(() => { $window.location.reload();});
```

¿Qué hago, me pongo a llorar?

Comment: ante de nada? quien usa internet explorer 11? en este momento? :/

Comment: uno de los clientes que estaba en el proceso de checkout y le lanzó error.

Comment: que raro que alguien use ese navegador :/

Comment: Es importante incluir en tu pregunta el error que se genera por el bloque de código que indicas.

Comment: ¡Verdad! X.x Olvidé agregar un elemento importante. Regresando al trabajo hago un rollback temporal para actualizar la pregunta. Disculpen el inconveniente.

Comment: Si desea que ese tipo de código funcione en IE11 sin editar cada parte del código ES6, tendrá que transpilarlo al código ES5 usando algo como Babel.

Comment: O el gran e ilustre transpiler ¡Typescript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tranquilo, respira hondo, vamos por partes hermano, primero lo primero, las arrow functions fueron creadas para ahorrar código equivalente (por así decirlo).

```
return availability.price && availability.options.filter(function(x){ x.leadTime >= 0}).length > 0;
```

Con respecto a lo segundo, esto te va a funcionar:

```
.then(function (result) { console.log(result); })
.finally(function () {
$window.location.reload();
});
```

De manera general:

Si encuentras una función del tipo arrow (flecha) y quieras mandarla a que sea compatible con IE 11, basta con agregar la mágica palabra `function` seguido del nombre de la variable como parámetro y en el caso que no tenga como en la línea del `.finally`, sólo agrega `function()`. Eso sí, recuerda eliminar la flecha `=>` y tener las llaves de inicio `{` y cierre `}` bien puestas.

Si deseas una mejor manera de programar usando `JavaScript` y que tu código sea adaptado a navegadores de menor versión, te recomiendo usar https://www.typescriptlang.org/